# Using java semaphores as locks between two Runnable classes

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, mutex, semaphore

I have three objects which are instances of two different classes implementing `Runnable` interface. One of the objects changes counters of the other two objects, but I want to make sure the whole update operation is not interrupted by the other threads (i.e. I want to use a lock for my critical section).

In the code below (this is an illustration of the actual code, not itself), I want to make sure the code in the critical section is executed without any interruptions.

One thought I have is defining a binary Semaphore, m, in the `Worker` class and surround every operation that touches `value` and `operations` with `m.acquire()` followed by `m.release()`. But, in the 'Runner' class, I have a call to `incrementValue()` and if I surround CS with `acquire()/release()` calls while I have the same thing within `incrementValue()`, it does not make sense.

I am a bit confused about where I should be putting my semaphores to achieve mutual exclusion.

Thanks

```
class Worker implements Runnable{
    int value;
    int operations;
    // Semaphore m = new Semaphore(1);
    ...
    ...
    void incrementValue(int n){
        // m.acquire() here??
        this.operations++;
        this.value += n;
        // m.release() here??
    }
    ...
    @Override
    public void run(){
        ...
        this.operations++;
        this.value = getRandomNum(); 
        ...
    }
}

class Runner implements Runnable {
    Worker a, b;
    ...
    ...
    @Override
    public void run(){
        ...
        // Start of the CS
        // a.m.acquire() here?
        // b.m.acquire() here?
        a.incrementValue(x);
        System.out.println("Value in WorkerA incremented by " + x);
        b.incrementValue(y);
        System.out.println("Value in WorkerB incremented by " + y);
        // a.m.release() here?
        // b.m.release() here?
        // end of the CS
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I just realised that `incrementValue()` is only called by the `Runner` thread and by nothing else. Hence, I would assume it should be okay not to use `acquire()/release()` inside of `incrementValue()` - it is used only one thread anyway (there is only one `Runner` thread and two `Worker` threads). As long as I have `acquire()/release()` inside of `Runner.run()` AND `Worker.run()`, which is another method modifying the `int` variables, I should be okay. Right?

Comment: Re, "`incrementValue()` only called by the `Runner` thread..." The purpose of locking is _not_ to keep multiple threads from using the same _method_ at the same time. The purpose is to keep them from accessing the same _data_ at the same time. If `incrementValue()` operates on the same variable that is used by other threads, then you must use a lock.

Comment: Thanks. The modification to `int` variables happen in different methods used by different threads. Then, I assume I have to control access to these variables _by using the same lock_ for every method attempting to modify the variables. i.e. an `m.lock()/m.unlock()` surrounding all the writes to these variables. right?

Comment: Yes. All of the threads that access the same shared data should lock the same shared lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the problem you are facing is the same problem that [`ReentrantLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) is meant to solve. `ReentrantLock` lets you do this:

```
final ReentrantLock m = new ReentrantLock();

void foo() {
    m.lock();
    doFooStuff();
    m.unlock();
}

void bar() {
    m.lock();
    foo();
    doAdditionalBarStuff();
    m.unlock();
}
```

The `lock()` call checks to see whether or not the calling thread already owns the lock. If the caller does not, then it first acquires the lock, waiting if necessary, and finally, before it returns it sets a `count` variable to 1.

Subsequent `lock()` calls from the same thread will see that the thread already owns the lock, and they will simply increment the counter and return.

The `unlock()` calls decrement the counter, and only release the lock when the count reaches zero.